# extract data from php array and provide a string

Tags: php

Know doubt simple...

DB looks like this

```
ID          CAT

2         0|6|0|9
```

In CAT the second no (6) I want to extract if the ID = 2 and put into a string so that I can say

```
if(string = 6)
    Then do x
```

using php...

Many Thanks

Comment: is the data stored in CAT already an Array or is it stored as a String like "0|6|0|9"?

Answer (score 0):

if it *really* is an array you'd be better of with a `foreach` structure.

```
$cat = array(2, 6, 0, 9);

foreach ( $cat as $c ) {
    if ( $c == 6 ) {
    // do X using PHP
    }
}
```

Have fun :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're searching for [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
foreach ($sqlRows as $sqlRow) {
    $categories = explode('|', $sqlRow['CAT']);
    if (in_array(6, $categories)) {
        var_dump($sqlRow['ID']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first do wth loop then use sql query you will get particular data or id.
$cat = array(2, 6, 0, 9);

```
foreach ( $cat as $c ) {
    if ( $c == 6 ) {
    mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users table where id=2);
    }
}
```